# Unit test ASP.net MVC JSON model binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, model-binding

I'm looking to unit test that the built-in JSON modelbinding in ASP.NET MVC is working as expected - meaning that my model definition correctly maps to the JSON string that I receive.

something along the lines of

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
   string json = @"{someProp:....}";
   MyModel mm = ASPNET_MVC_JSON_Deserailizer<MyModel>(json);
   Assert.Equal("myval", mm.SomeProp);
}
```

What is the actual code that can be put in for `ASPNET_MVC_JSON_Deserailizer<MyModel>`

Answer (score 0):

It uses [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). But unit testing that the model binding which is part of the framework correctly deserializes JSON strings looks unnecessary to me. Hopefully Microsoft already did those tests when they designed the framework, so why repeat those tests? Don't you think that it would be better to unit test your code instead?